# lvm Remove missing physical volumes

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I have an logical volume /home which shows missing physical volumes. "Couldn't find device with uuid 'jhueouoe-eoueok-ceokek-chkoke'". I had removed that physical volume some time back(after migating the data). Now my question is how can i clean up the logical volume metadata? I am not able to add new physical volumes because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this was easy. vgreduce --removemissing did the job for me. Guess was too hasty in posting the question.